# Missing files in local SVN working copy

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

**Problem:** Eclipse does not download certain files that are present in the remote SVN repository. I do synchronize with Subclipse, but it keeps telling me, my working copy is up-to-date. However, I can see there are additional files in the remote repository when I view the project in WebSVN. I can even see the empty Java package in Eclipse that is supposed to hold the missing files, but the files are not there. I checked the file system and the files are in fact missing.

I tried updating to HEAD, ran the cleanup command in the "Team" menu and tried to revert the Java package (but there are no changes to revert). How can I fix this problem and force Eclipse/Subclipse to re-checkout any missing files?

**My setup:**

- Eclipse Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)
- Subclipse 1.10.11

Comment: are these files under a subdirectory?

Comment: Yes, the Java packages are represented by a tree-like structure of sub folders.

Answer (score 2):

In SVN, there is something called [Sparse Directories](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html).

From svn book:

> By default, most Subversion operations on directories act in a
>   recursive manner. For example, svn checkout creates a working copy
>   with every file and directory in the specified area of the repository,
>   descending recursively through the repository tree until the entire
>   structure is copied to your local disk. Subversion 1.5 introduces a
>   feature called sparse directories (or shallow checkouts) that allows
>   you to easily check out a working copy—or a portion of a working
>   copy—more shallowly than full recursion, with the freedom to bring in
>   previously ignored files and subdirectories at a later time.

If for some reason your `checkout` wasn't fully recursive, the `update` command will only update the files according to the depth of the checkout.

To force a fully recursive update, open a terminal or cmd in your working directory and type the command:

```
svn update --depth infinity
```

Comment: I can update my working copy using ``svn up --set-depth=infinity`` on the command line. However, I'd like to use the Subversive plug-in of Eclipse. Is there any such option within the plug-in? The strange thing is that it used to work with Eclipse in the past, but then broke.